# Use mouse to explore data displayed in python using matplotlib.pyplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I use the mouse to explore a plot or image displayed in python?

I would like to:

- use markers (add/remove/manipulate)
- sample the data values (at plot/image/mesh)
- continue evaluating code lines in the console

I am currently using matplotlib.pyplot for the display and mpldatacursor for interaction. is there better way?

my system (get stuck and crash too often) is: win7, python 2.7.6, matplotlib 1.4.2, mpldatacursor 0.5